# Scala package objects and Play! 2

Tags: scala, scope, package, playframework-2.0

I have a Play! 2 application and some functions that are reused across models. I thought to put them inside the `models` package object, as in the following example

```
import java.util.Date

package object models {
  case class RichDate(d: Date) {
    def timestamp: Long = d.getTime / 1000
  }

  implicit def enrich(d: Date): RichDate = new RichDate(d)
}
```

so that everywhere I have a date field in a model I can write `myDate.timestamp`.ù

This compiles and even works in unit tests. For some reason, though, when I run the actual application, I get an Execution Exception `[NoSuchMethodError: models.package$.enrich(Ljava/util/Date;)Lmodels/package$RichDate;]`

> Is there a reason why the above should not work in a Play! application, while being valid Scala?

Comment: try getting rid of the case in `case class`, no need to new a case class, that may be the issue

Comment: Nope, it still does not work. :-/

Comment: try breaking the implicit out into a trait and then just have something like, "package object models extends PackageBase"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've run across this as well and it turned out that the weird behavior was due to `package object models` [already being defined in the framework](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/models/package.scala). This basically makes the `package object models` off limits to users of the framework. My solution was to put my library pimping in utility objects (such as utils.DateUtils) and just import them when appropriate.

Comment: Thank you! It would have taken quite a lot to find out by myself!